# Symfony database password using special characters

Tags: database, symfony, passwords

I'm actually having an issue with Symfony and my database password. The password contains several special characters such as for example : `65RfK_&$+4`

Reading the doc, they said that we actually need to escape those special characters such as :

```
php symfony generate:app --csrf-secret=Unique\$ecret backend
```

However, I tried to apply this on my password but it's still not working :

```
65RfK_\&\$\+4
```

The cached file generate a password such as  :

```
65RfK_\\&\\$\\+4
```

Since I can't change the password, I need to find a way to make it works. Any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT :**
It seems that the problem comes from the `+` symbol. However, trying to escape it does not work :

```
65RfK_&$\+4
\u0024\u0026\u002b2
```

**Poblem solved**
I finally solved my problem. I contacted the administrator and ask for a new password without the `+` sign. It works well now. However, I'm still curious about how to escape it from a YAML file. If anyone has an answer, I will be more than glad to see it :)

Answer (score 1):

Where is your database password? In the `app/config/parameters.yml`, right? Did you try to add simple or double quotes before and after your password?

For example:

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
    [...]
    database_password: "65RfK_&$+4"
```

Comment: Hi, my password is located in `config/database.yml` for that application. I tried to use double and single quote but it still not working. On my local machine, I tried to do the same and that's how I found out that the `+` sign was the cause of the problem. Without it, it works well

Answer (score 0):

If the username, password, host or database name contain any character considered special in a URI (such as `+`, `@`, `$`, `#`, `/`, `:`, `*`, `!`), you must encode them. You can use `urlencode` function to encode them.

After that, remove the `resolve:` prefix in `config/packages/doctrine.yaml` to avoid errors: `url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'`